# Need help some code that isn't working

Tags: php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $follow = strip_tags($_POST["follow"]);
    $follow = addslashes($follow);
    $follow = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $follow);
    $sesid = $_SESSION["id"];
    $rowid = $row['id'];
    $followers = $conn->query("INSERT INTO followers (forid, fromid) VALUES ('$rowid', '$sesid'");
    echo "<h3><center>Sucessfully followed!</center></h3>";
}
```

It doesn't seem to work. It doesn't throw any errors. I'm a new(er) PHP developer. Thank you!

Comment: You don't check for errors. You should parameterize the query. What are you doing with `$follow` doesnt seem to be used. Where does `$row` come from?

Comment: Oh, didn't mean to add unicode. Aswell as forgetting to say "Before I prepare, i usually do a proof-of-concept." $row is from earlier in the php file, basically get a specific row in the database.

Comment: Why are you doing all the escaping and sanitizing on the variable you aren't using in mysql? What does `$followers` come out to be?

Comment: I'm going back and thinking about why I even escaped/santizied that variable. $followers comes out to be nothing as I don't seem to get an error as well as anything else.

Comment: You did `var_dump` on it and it is just nothing? You need to use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: I've already used error reporting, nothing popped up. I'm honestly confused as I'm a rookie and probably have a lot of learning to do. var_dump didn't seem to print/echo/dump anything.

Comment: Tried something, $followers = $conn->query("INSERT INTO followers (forid, fromid) VALUES ($rowid, $sesid"); is returning false.

Comment: Please add the code where you are using error reporting.

Comment: @drifttwo which query is the one you are running the one in that comment or the one in the question? That comment is missing a `)`.... actually both queries are missing the closing `)` on the `VALUES`.

Answer (score 1):

**STOP** this madness... Do not insert values into a query, that's how bad things happen.

Also, add some error checking here and there, it's impossible to know what's wrong with the piece of code (or is it?):

Try something more like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db_name');
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
  throw new Exception('Connection Error' . $conn->connect_err);
}
```

Now let's deal with the post data:

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
  $follow = $_POST["follow"];
  $sesid = $_SESSION["id"];
  $rowid = $row['id']; // don't know where this is coming from

  if($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO followers (forid, fromid) VALUES (?, ?)") {
    $stmt->bind_param('si', $follow, $sesid);
    if(!$stmt->execute()) {
      throw new Exception('Error! Could not execute query.');
    }

    $stmt->close();
  } else {
    throw new Exception('Could not prepare query!');
  }
} else {
  // Add a error checking here
  throw new Exception('No post data');
}
```

Prepared statements will help you avoid anyone trying to insert undesired content into your query (SQL injection).

The way it works,

1. Prepare the query (`$conn->prepare()`)

   - Note here that there are simple `?` where the values would otherwise be. That's for our next step.
2. Bind the parameters of your query with `$stmt->bind_param()`. This will tell PHP where each value should go, starting at the second parameter position.

   - The documentation for the `bind_param` function: `bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )`
   - A little explanation for the first param:

     - `s` - stands for string (the `$follow`, I assume is a string)
     - `i` - stands for integer. The session ID
3. Then, finally, execute the query (`$stmt->execute()`). That will do the hard work of adding the values to your database.
4. Explicitly close the connection to your database (`$conn->close()`);

Read more on [PHP's official documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @user3783243 you're right... I removed that from my answer